# Unable to get results from Solr for the Multilist values using Sitecore 9.3 code

Tags: solr

I'm upgrading our application from Sitecore 8.2 to 9.3 and we are working on Solr 8.1 where there are lots of multilist fields available as below:
`"document_languages_sm":["af58419145c9420187405409f4cf8bdd", "96f021639342449088cf73b79727a58e", "0ac792397513488bb1bb3dadc248270e"], "video_languages_sm":["af58419145c9420187405409f4cf8bdd"]` and so on

And we are defining these multilist in Sitecore 9.3 code as below:

```
 [IndexField(Constants.IndexFields.DocumentLanguages)]
    public List<string> DocumentLanguages { get; set; }

    [IndexField(Constants.IndexFields.VideoLanguage)]
    public List<string> VideoLanguages { get; set; }
```

And this is how we have mapped the Solr fields in our local

```
 public const string DocumentLanguages = "document_languages_sm";
 public const string VideoLanguages = "video_languages_sm";
```

But we are getting 0 results for the below code though the results are available in Solr:

```
  queryable = FilterOnLocation(queryable, rootItems, excludedRootItems, query.Language).Cast<IndexedItem>();
            resultItem = queryable.GetResults();
```

We are getting results for other datatypes like "string" but not for `List<string>`. Could anyone suggest us on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Change your property types from `List<string>` to `IEnumerable<ID>` and add `[TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]` attribute.

It is possible that Sitecore cannot convert from field which comes back from Solr to `List<string>` as it's not defined in config.

So it would be:

```
[IndexField(Constants.IndexFields.DocumentLanguages)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
public IEnumerable<ID> DocumentLanguages { get; set; }

[IndexField(Constants.IndexFields.VideoLanguage)]
[TypeConverter(typeof(IndexFieldEnumerableConverter))]
public IEnumerable<ID> VideoLanguages { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried the above solution...but it did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to use at mapping the field names without **_sm** suffix, and try to the type to IEnumerable.

I had same issue before, and if the aboves doesn't work add by field names in index configuration like the following:

```
<fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
    <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
         <field fieldName="document_languages" returnType="stringCollection" />
         <field fieldName="video_languages" returnType="stringCollection" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with sitecore 10. Sitecore uses a GUID list for a multilist. If you check your configs, it should add a _sm to the formater:

```
<typeMatch type="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Guid]" typeName="guidCollection" fieldNameFormat="{0}_sm" multiValued="true" settingType="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchFieldConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider"/>
```

notice the type is a List of GUIDS, not IDs.

Try to change your code to

```
public List<GUID> DocumentLanguages { get; set; }
public List<GUID> VideoLanguages { get; set; }
```